# Resource Pool для настройки vSphere plug-in в Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, vmware

пробую указать разный путь к Resource Pool

[image: path]

в итоге получаю

```
[vSphere] Error cloning VM or template
org.jenkinsci.plugins.vsphere.tools.VSphereNotFoundException: vSphere Error: Resource pool "/Kovalenko/Kovalenko/Kovalenko/192.168.140.21/Kovalenko" not found
```

Как правильно указать пути?

Собственно, необходимо заполнить следующие поля

- CLUSTER : ?
- RESOURCE POOL : ?
- DATASTORE : в моем случае это HP-RAID50

[image: Datastore]

Сами поля в Jenkins плагине выглядят так

[image: Jenkins vSphere plug-in]

добавлю скрин vms & templates
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не туда смотрите. откройме инвентори -> vm & tamplates

Comment: лучше удалите картинку и замените на ту, что показывает, нажав на править

Comment: я понял в чем ошибка. у вас на хосте нет вообще никаких Resource pool. поэтому выдал такую ошибку. нужно создать руками и прописать имя

Comment: запросил у виртуальщиков. Сам не имею доступа к таким правкам. А без RP никак нельзя? может какой-нибудь root-овый пул указать? (видел одето краем глаза, пока гуглил проблему)

Comment: пробуйте. но без совсем никак. так как в исходниках  делается проверка